# parameterized console character positioning

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm not sure how to dynamically adjust characters in a function I'm using to write to a console where there are strict locations necessary in addition to dynamic scalability that you could get from 'format table', but I'm looking to do things a little differently so I can get away from needing an file.

I've put in a 2nd item on the list only for reference to see the context of the issue, I've found a way to draw an entire array or pull from a hash table with this method, but I'm trying to find a way to not need so many predefined character lists, etc. For instance, the two $top and $bot arrays, I'm aware that can be done with a couple of the suggestions that were listed... just not sure how to get the words to display in the format correctly, and if the characters exceed a certain threshhold, then it'd have the trailing dots, like format-table kind of does... Here's the context. It's a bit more verbatim to my actual code.

```
function Wrap-Top {[CmdLetBinding()]Param()                                                                                                                                
$top=@([PSCustomObject]@(                                                                             
"                                                                                            ";
" //-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_\\ ";
" \\- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - // ";
" //                                                                                      \\ ";));                                                                                           
Write-Output $top;}; 

function Wrap-Bot {[CmdLetBinding()]Param()
$bot=@([PSCustomObject]@(
" //                                                                                      \\ ";
" \\ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -// ";
" //_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-\\ ";
"";));
Write-Output $bot;};

Function Wrap-Action {[CmdletBinding()]Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][Alias("#")][String]$Type)
[Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline=$True)][Alias("@")][String]$Description)
Begin{Wrap-Top}
Process{(Write-Output " \\ [ $($Text) ] @: )(Write-Output "$($Description)" }
End{Wrap-Bot}}

Wrap-Action -Type "Item1" -Description "$($i.0)"

"                                                                                            ";
" //-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_\\ ";
" \\- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - // ";
" //                                                                                      \\ ";
" \\                                                                                      // ";
" //             Item1 : $($i.0)";
" \\             Item2 : $($i.1)";                                                                                    
" //                                                                                      // ";
" \\                                                                                      \\ ";
" // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -// ";
" \\_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-\\ ";
"";));
```

Comment: get the length of the status text & use string multiplication to set the length of the hyphens. you can use `'-' * 50` to get a line of 50 hyphens ... [*grin*]

Comment: that's not a bad idea but this is just an example, I'm trying to make it so that the slashes at the right are always there.

Comment: ah! [*grin*] well, get the length of the widest of the two possible lines, then pad the middle one if needed. take a look at `.PadLeft()` & `.PadRight()`

Comment: I see, I can try that. Would you happen to have maybe an example of how you would arrange that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the space dash pattern, the following script compensates for odd `$Text.Length`

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\23\SO_55802986.ps1
Function Wrap-Status ($Text){
    $PadEven = $Text.Length % 2 # pad to even length
    $Pad = [math]::Max(10,$Text.Length+$PadEven)

    '// - - - - - - - - - {0}\\'    -f        ('- '*($Pad/2))
    '\\ [ Processing : {0} ]{1} //' -f  $Text,(' '*($Pad-$Text.Length))
    '// - - - - - - - - - {0}\\'    -f        ('- '*($Pad/2))
    ''
}

$Array = 'this','55555','88888888','999999999','1010101010','11111111111',
         '14141414141414','151515151515151','Five_ThisGoesOutToColumn26'

ForEach ($Text in $Array){Wrap-Status $Text}
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\04\23\SO_55802986.ps1
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : this ]       //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : 55555 ]      //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : 88888888 ]   //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : 999999999 ]  //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : 1010101010 ] //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : 11111111111 ]  //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : 14141414141414 ] //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : 151515151515151 ]  //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
\\ [ Processing : Five_ThisGoesOutToColumn26 ] //
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \\
```

Comment: Alright... I'm going to repost an actual example of the code i've got, since I think it's being a bit misunderstood...

I'm not trying to extend the bar across the screen. It'll always be a fixed length.
What I'm trying to do is essentially find a way to dynamically structure the content and it's width, and if the string happens to exceed a certain threshold, then it does the trailing dots and that the last 2 slashes on the right of this fixed box will always be there and correct. BTW, what does the -f switch mean/do, formatting?

its strange that i have xaml down, but consoles harder lol

Comment: Yes, the -f is for the format operator read [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: I'll check that out. I updated the example I'm inquiring about, I think some of what you listed points me in the general direction of just using the math function to figure out what needs to be done structurally, but as far as the dynamic content and variability, I'm not certain that it helps with the example I've updated in entirety. Item1 may be 5 characters or it may be 10, less is better but always put that toward the colon so that the table isn't randomly sliding the text around. the right side of the colon would always have no more than x characters, and always list those slashes

Comment: ooo the f operator is exactly what I was looking for to do all of this. I think that's gonna help me figure this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do the centering. [*grin*] i am confident there are simpler, more direct methods ... but i can't think of any just now. [*blush*]

if you decide to use this, i recommend you convert it into a function that can be gracefully called by the part of your code that needs it.

my personal opinion is that this is ... a *huge waste of time*. every screen write slows down your script so it is usually worth while to *reduce* the number of screen writes, not *increase* them.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$StatusItemList = @'
One
TwoIsTheNumberOfThisItem
Ee-Thray
ForForeFour
Five_ThisGoesOutToColumn26
Six
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$StartTB_Line = '//'
$EndTB_Line = '\\'
$FillerTB_Line = '-'
$StandardWidth = 20
$StartStatusLine = $EndTB_Line
$EndStatusLine = $StartTB_Line


foreach ($SIL_Item in $StatusItemList)
    {
    $SL_Text = '[ Processing : {0} ]' -f $SIL_Item
    if ($SL_Text.Length -gt ($StandardWidth - 2))
        {
        $Width = $SL_Text.Length + 2
        }
        else
        {
        $Width = $SL_Text.Length
        }
    $Padding = [int](($Width - $SL_Text.Length) / 2)
    $Centered = -join @((' ' * $Padding), $SL_Text, (' ' * $Padding))

    $TB_Line = -join @($StartTB_Line, ($FillerTB_Line * $Width), $EndTB_Line)
    $S_Line = -join @($StartStatusLine, $Centered, $EndStatusLine)

    $TB_Line
    $S_Line
    $TB_Line
    ''
    }
```

output ...

```
//----------------------\\
\\ [ Processing : One ] //
//----------------------\\

//-------------------------------------------\\
\\ [ Processing : TwoIsTheNumberOfThisItem ] //
//-------------------------------------------\\

//---------------------------\\
\\ [ Processing : Ee-Thray ] //
//---------------------------\\

//------------------------------\\
\\ [ Processing : ForForeFour ] //
//------------------------------\\

//---------------------------------------------\\
\\ [ Processing : Five_ThisGoesOutToColumn26 ] //
//---------------------------------------------\\

//----------------------\\
\\ [ Processing : Six ] //
//----------------------\\
```

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but it's not exactly what I'm trying to do- although, this definitely helps me learn a bit more about how to make things more dynamic on screen.

Basically I have a script that I'm using these wrappers on, so whenever it gets to a function, I have it print that so the user can see it. 'processing' is just an example of my actual use case for this. the width will always be a fixed width, the problem is that when I put in different strings, they're all different lengths, so the centering and the length stuff sort of matters... still, I appreciate your input!

Comment: I was able to reconstitute the math you used to get the effect I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelC.CookSr. - glad to know that you were able to use it! [*grin*]

Comment: Yeah I'm having a field day with it to be perfectly honest.

$li=(" "*92);echo($li);
$lb=" //";$rb="\\ ";$mi=(92-($lb.length+$rb.length));$x=($mi/2);$mi=("-_"*$x);$li=($lb+$mi+$rb);echo ($li);
$lb=" \\-";$rb=" // ";$mi=(92-($lb.length+$rb.length));$x=($mi/2);$mi=(" -"*$x);$li=($lb+$mi+$rb);echo ($li);
$lb=" // ";$rb=" \\ ";$th="[ Provisional-Root ]";if(($th.length)%2-ne0){$y=($th.Replace(']',' ]'));$th=$y};
$x=((92-($lb.length+$rb.Length+$th.Length))/4);$lm=("- "*$x);$rm=(" -"*$x);$li=($lb+$lm+$th+$rm+$rb);echo($li)

dynamic vectors > static strings : you're the man

Comment: other than the icky short $VarNames, it looks good ... [*grin*]

Comment: Pretty cool that I was able to concat that all down to this... prolly why you were smiling lol. This doesn't have percentages in there but it's the least amount of code necessary, kinda what I was looking to do. Kinda looks like regex

echo(" "*92);echo(" //"+("-_"*43)+"\\");echo(" \\-"+(" -"*42)+" // ")

Comment: @MichaelC.CookSr. - am no fan of code golf ... but i can admire the effort while condemning the future maintenance headaches. [*grin*]

Comment: Well... I can understand that. Regardless, I appreciate your help!